# highlight certain values in a pseudocolor plot

Tags: matlab, plot

I have a very basic question regarding plotting pseudocolor plots in matlab. Say if I have a plot  as follows:

```
d1 = 1:4;
d2 = 1:4;
dat = [2,3,4,1;...
    3,4,7,1;...
    8,7,6,1;...
    2,3,3,1];
pcolor(d1,d2,dat);shading interp
```

Is it then possible for me to draw a line on this plot which highlights certain values, such as draw a line through values = 5? Please note that I want to avoid using contourf and would like to use pcolor in this instance.

Comment: Just use `hold on` and plot anything on top of your `pcolor` plot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `contour` to plot contour lines over your `pcolor` plot.

```
d1 = 1:4;
d2 = 1:4;
dat = [2,3,4,1;...
3,4,7,1;...
8,7,6,1;...
2,3,3,1];
pcolor(d1,d2,dat);
shading interp
hold on

%# use the same contour level twice if you only have a single one
contour(dat,[5 5],'color','k','lineWidth',2)
```

[image]

Comment: @EitanT: Indeed I did. Fixed now.